# illness<- Blood pressure < x

Tags: r

I have a health data set. Blood pressure is one of their variable, I want to define blood pressure more than x is illness. How can I manage it? I try threshould defining order but it does not work.

I expect to define Bloodpresure>=160 is an illness. then according to this, anlyse bloodpressure for sex and age groups

Comment: `illness <- ifelse(Bloodpressure >= 160, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck